# Capturing coordinates and displaying divs on it

Tags: jquery, html

I have a main div and i want to place some more divs on the coordinates which is captured when i click on it. Its working fine, it changes the top and left position of the div, but problem is that when i click again on the main div it drags the div which is already displayed on the first click. I want div which is displayed on the first click to stop moving when i click again on the main div. Help really appreciated.

Code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_div").click(function(event, ui){

    var x = event.pageX-document.getElementById("main_div").offsetLeft;
    var y = event.pageY-document.getElementById("main_div").offsetTop;

    document.pointform.form_x.value = x;
    document.pointform.form_y.value = y;


    $("#container-5").css({"top":y,"left":x});
    $("#EDate").css({"top":y,"left":x});

 });
 });
```

Comment: you better add a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net , so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you just want to remove the event handler, you can use the [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_div").click(function(event, ui){

    var x = event.pageX-document.getElementById("main_div").offsetLeft;
    var y = event.pageY-document.getElementById("main_div").offsetTop;

    document.pointform.form_x.value = x;
    document.pointform.form_y.value = y;


    $("#container-5").css({"top":y,"left":x});
    $("#EDate").css({"top":y,"left":x});

    // and here we unbind it
    $(this).unbind('click');

   });
});
```

Per your comment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").click(function(event, ui){
    var i = 0;
    if($(this).data("index"))
      i = $(this).data("index");
    else
      $(this).data("index", i = 0);

    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;


    if($("#container-" + i)[0])
        $("#container-" + i).css({"top":y,"left":x});
    else
        $(this).unbind("click");


    $(this).data("index",i+1);


   });
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9Xx/show
Source: http://jsfiddle.net/Sn9Xx/

Comment: What if i want to add one more div to different position on main_div click? say div id="container-6"?

Comment: You could use the data attribute of the main div to store an index and base it off that.  I'll add an edit.

Comment: Thanks but i think you didnt understand my question. See Remove that EDate part. now running your first code will paste Container-5 on main_div click. Perfect. Now onclicking again it should change the css of the div which i want to display and should not affect the position of Container-5. Hope you understood?

Comment: @shabbir.rang I believe I understand what you need.  I just ran off to make a quick demo.  I've added the demo to my answer and updated the second code section.  Does that work as you expected?

Comment: Right. But what if the divs which i am calling have been named as id=asdf, id= abcd, id= xyz ?

Comment: @shabbir.rang Then add them to an array at some point: `myOddlyNamedDivs = ["asdf","abcd","xyz"]` and refference the array when you apply the css: `$("#"+myOddlyNamedDivs[i]).css({"top":y,"left":x});`

Comment: @shabbir.rang  You're welcome and glad I could help. :)  If you have any other questions or need any of my spaghetti code clarified, feel free to ask. (I'll have to answer when it's morning though XD)